# onmouseover - pass alt tag with image tag

Tags: javascript

I've got the following code that is viewed as thumbnail images beside the big preview image.

```
<img onmouseover="getElementById('preview').src=(this.src)" src="images/1.jpg" alt="TESTING 1">
<img onmouseover="getElementById('preview').src=(this.src)" src="images/2.jpg" alt="TESTING 2">
<img onmouseover="getElementById('preview').src=(this.src)" src="images/3.jpg" alt="TESTING 3">
```

Then I've got my preview image...

```
<div class="preview" align="center"><img id="preview" src="images/1.jpg" alt="TESTING 1" /></div>
```

When hovering over the thumbnail, it updates the preview.  I'd like to pass the alt attribute to the preview.

---

I've tried this...

```
<img onmouseover="getElementById('preview').src=(this.src).setAttribute('alt',this.alt)" src="images/1.jpg" alt="TESTING 1">
```

and this...

```
<img onmouseover="getElementById('preview').src=(this.src).alt(this.alt)" src="images/1.jpg" alt="TESTING 1">
```

neither of which worked.  I'm not the best at coming up with my own javascript but I'm obviously doing something wrong

Comment: You need to learn the basics of Javascript.  Your code makes no sense.

Comment: I've never tried to pass alt tag before...so I just tried something to see if it would work.  I looked up how to retrieve the alt tag and it showed that, so I made an effort.  Its called trial and error...you know, a learning thing.

Comment: the code works except for passing the alt attribute....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will allways have better results if yopu take your js into another function.

I created the `changePreview` function for you.

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```js
function changePreview(thumb){
var preview = document.getElementById('preview')
var title = document.getElementById('pre-title')
  preview.src=(thumb.src);
  preview.alt=(thumb.alt);
  title.innerHTML = preview.alt;
  console.log('New alt: '+preview.alt);
}
```

```html
<img onmouseover="changePreview(this)" src="images/1.jpg" alt="TESTING 1">
<img onmouseover="changePreview(this)" src="images/2.jpg" alt="TESTING 2">
<img onmouseover="changePreview(this)" src="images/3.jpg" alt="TESTING 3">

<div class="preview" align="center"><img id="preview" src="images/1.jpg" alt="TESTING 1" /></div>
<p id="pre-title"></p>
```

Comment: that worked.  Is there an easy way to display the "alt" tag as text below the image where I can style it?  Or am I supposed to use the "title" tag?  I want the div with the alt/title text to display `position: absolute; bottom: 0; height: 40px;` at the bottom of the preview box if there is "text"...if no text, nothing displays.

Comment: I think you should use an html tag an not an attribut for that. Happy it helped. Don't forget to upvote or accept if it solved your problem

Comment: kinda hard to use an html tag since the preview image changes via thumbnail mouseover

Comment: Why not you ask this question as a new one, and post the link here. I will love helping you

Comment: I'll continue doing research.  I have no clue where to even begin trying this and posting a question without trying and without code proving that you have tried is not recommended and will probably get me downvotes before anyone even has a chance to begin answering.  I'd prefer to keep positive rep on here

Comment: the preview text shows up now...that part works great.  But the image doesnt change in preview.

Comment: nevermind...somehow added additiona code by accident...works great..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option

**Option-1:** Add assigning alt with semi colon separated

```
<img onmouseover="getElementById('preview').src=(this.src);getElementById('preview').alt=(this.alt)" src="images/1.jpg" alt="TESTING 1">
<img onmouseover="getElementById('preview').src=(this.src);getElementById('preview').alt=(this.alt)" src="images/2.jpg" alt="TESTING 2">
<img onmouseover="getElementById('preview').src=(this.src);getElementById('preview').alt=(this.alt)" src="images/3.jpg" alt="TESTING 3">
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GQVZxL?editors=1010

**Option2:** Using onmouseover event function

```
<img onmouseover="preview(this)" src="images/1.jpg" alt="TESTING 1">
<img onmouseover="preview(this)" src="images/2.jpg" alt="TESTING 2">
<img onmouseover="preview(this)" src="images/3.jpg" alt="TESTING 3">

<div class="preview" align="center"><img id="preview" src="images/1.jpg" alt="TESTING 1" /></div>
```

JS:

```
function preview(e){
   document.getElementById('preview').alt = e.alt;
   document.getElementById('preview').src = e.src;
}
```

Code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/OQKNZK?editors=1010